# Testing the NotificationsCompat.Builder class on Android O give me the following error

Tags: android, notifications

I'm trying to work with the new Android O.

I've download the latest sdk, and on my gradle.properties there is the following configuration:

```
MinSDKVersion=26
TargetSDKVersion=26
CompileSDKVersion=26
```

But I cannot compile because I've got the following error:

```
error: cannot find symbol method setChannelId(String)
```

According to google this function is introduced in the sdk 26

Any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you are using version `26.0.1` or higher of the support libraries (e.g., `com.android.support:support-compat`.

Also make sure that you are using `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`, not `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`.

Comment: I'm using v4 and the version 26.0.1 from the support libraries.

Comment: @Hug: I suggest that you edit your question to include a [mcve], which would include your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`) and the source file in which you are attempting to use `setChannelId()`.

Comment: Added the following support library to my gradle dependences: compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1'

Had to add google repository: maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

Comment: In my case, the problem was support library version. Updated to 26.0.2 and problem solved.